# How to get the default page?

Tags: python, firefox

How can I get and read the default home page of the firefox brower using Python programming language ? I would love to reset it back if someone has changed it. If you give me a hint on how to get the default home page using a given Python API it will be enough for me.
Note: I use Windows XP as my OS.

Comment: What operating system are we talking here?

Comment: I use Windows XP. I reedited my question after you asked me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### IE

That information resides somewhere in the registry on windows machines. You can read the registry with the python module winreg.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html

You can find the registry locations [here](https://superuser.com/questions/287313/which-registry-keys-need-to-be-edited-to-change-the-default-browser).

### Firefox

Firefox saves its settings somewhere in your application data folder. For me this is

> %appdata%/Mozilla/Firefox/pk33aan6.default/prefs.js

Somewhere in **prefs.js** you will find this:

```
user_pref("browser.startup.homepage", "about:blank");
```

Changing *about:blank* to *http://google.com* and clearing the contents of **sessionstore.js** made Firefox load up google upon starting it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint, I will do that (i have no idea for the moment in which windows registry it is stored), and I wait for other answers.

Comment: Aparently it is IE that saves its home page in registry, not Firefox :(

Comment: Oh, sorry. Ill take another look.

Comment: But your information is still useful for me because I need to read the default page location of IE browser too, so now I can do it with the _winreg you gave me above

Comment: Yes, you are right. I use a different Firefox version, but I looked for the JS file you showed me and I found the default home page there !!! Thank you very much.